# Autofit string derived from JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to show data derived from JSON object. JSON object contains a long string like:

```
"String":"<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
make a type specimen book.</p>"
```

I use this code to load this value

```
data-ng-bind-html="getHtml(selectedCategoryData[indexOfSelectedData].String)"
```

This does not create new line and show the entire string in a single line. When device width ends, it hides the rest of the text from that string.

I want to autofit the string. When device width ends it automatically creates a line break which normal `<p>` tag does.

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: need to provide a demo or at least to enough code to replicate this. We have no idea what css is being used to cause an issue like this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is more of a styling issue than a JSON issue. Could you try using the following CSS on the container?

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
```

If I'm off here, providing a JSFiddle of what's happening may be helpful.